# Как сделать Multi Step by step форму где каждая страница будет отправлять данные через POST?

Tags: php, jquery

у меня есть страница регистрации где каждая форма обращается к отдельному адресу.
Например у меня 3 страницы:

1. Страница ввода Ф.И.О
2. Страница ввода Данных для оплаты
3. Страница ввода данных о своей компании

Все эти данные хранятся в отдельных таблицах. Я думал через  указать страницы куда они отправляются но не знаю возможно ли это ли нет? При этом страницы не должны перезагружаться а должны перейти на следующую страницы с анимацией

Answer (score 0):

можно упустить функционал формы и кнопки submit и сделать через javascript/jquery и ajax, в javascript собираешь данные из полей формы и по клику на какую-то отдельную кнопку (элемент) отправляешь на нужный адресс и там уже обрабатываешь

Comment: А как с переходом быть? Если я запишу две функции на одну кнопку работать будет?

Comment: @SocialEmotion как вариант:  для каждого действия одна кнопка, первая кнопка делает отправку данных на один адресс и перерисовывает страницу чтобы выдать вторую форму со второй кнопкой, эта вторая кнопка уже делает отправку данных на другой адресс и переход к третьему шагу. Но лучше всего делать это не так. Так как это регистрация, то нельзя пачками отправлять данные, вдруг он на втором шаге передумает регистрироваться, а с первого шага данные запишутся, поэтому предыдущие формы просто скрывай и на последнем шаге на кнопку "завершить регистрацию" выполняешь отправку с трех форм куда тебе надо